# DiscordAPIError 10007 unknown member

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

## how to fix this DiscordAPIError 10007 unknown member

```js
  async execute(interaction) {
    const { channel, options } = interaction;

    const user = options.getUser("target");
    const reason = options.getString("reason") || `\`ไม่ได้กรอกเหตุผล\``;

    const member = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(user.id);

    const errEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle("**Mibow so cutest**")
    .setDescription(`คุณไม่สามารถใช้คำสั่งนี้กับ \`${user.username}\` ยศอาจจะสูงกว่าหรือเท่ากับตัวคุณ.`)
    .setColor(0xf44336)
    .setTimestamp();

    if (member.roles.highest.position >= interaction.member.roles.highest.position)
      return interaction.reply({ embeds: [errEmbed], ephemeral: true });

    await member.ban({ reason });
```

How to fix this error, thanks very much

Comment: # top of code
```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName("ban")
  .setDescription("แบนเมมเบอร์")
  .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator)
  .addUserOption(option =>
    option.setName("target")
    .setDescription("แท็ก/เลขไอดีเมมเบอร์")
    .setRequired(true)
  )
  .addStringOption(option =>
    option.setName("reason")
    .setDescription("เหตุผลที่แบน")
  ),
```

Comment: #under of code
```js
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle("**Mibow so cutest**")
    .setDescription(`คุณได้แบน ${user} ออกจากเซิร์ฟเวอร์แล้ว, เหตุผล : \`${reason}\``)
    .setColor(0xfff2cc)
    .setTimestamp();

    await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [embed],
    });
  }
}
```